# what does "abandoned" mean with catkin build?

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`catkin build` tells me that some number of packages in my workspace are "abandoned". what does this mean? Is there some way to list which packages are abandoned?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376616/what-does-%22abandoned%22-mean-with-catkin-build?/) by [LukeAI](https://answers.ros.org/users/38953/lukeai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2021-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It basically means those have not been included in the current build (as in: not by choice or request of the user, but because circumstances made it impossible to include them or finish building them).

Typically caused by (one of) their dependencies having failed to build.

Taken from [the source](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/blob/fc555e7602c6fd4dd546716d746411a4de74a165/catkin_tools/execution/executor.py#L209-L210):

> ```
> # List of jobs whose deps failed
> ```

```
abandoned_jobs = []
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1